# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 developer toolkit - "JaxRsWebModuleInfoBuilder" and "AnalyticsRESTDataStore" error in start of local WAS Liberty instance

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

After installing developer toolkit, when I'm trying to start the development server by "run" command. Following errors are consistently being reported by the server.

```
FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnalyticsConsole com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.component.JaxRsWebModuleInfoBuilder 333" at ffdc_16.12.27_20.11.09.0.log

0000006f com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.ilmt.MFPILMTLogger          E FWLSE0367E: Missing License Report data. Failed to create an ILMT record.

00000065 com.ibm.mobile.analytics.sdk.AnalyticsRESTDataStore          E MSAN020E: Non-success response code received in AnalyticsRESTDataStore: 404.
```

**Environment details**:

- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V8.0
- IBM MobileFirst Platform    Developer Kit for Windows (Release date
  02 September 2016)
- OS:    Windows 7

Comment: Are you notifying actual problems during your development or runtime? Or you are simply reporting errors you have observed in the log? These may be benign.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I've not faced any problem in development so far as I just finished the developer toolkit installation and was just validating if it is successful or not. I thought to ignore message.log errors, but FFDC logging at each restart is making me suspicious about the successful installation. Do you suggest that I can ignore ffdc reporting and continue with development?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The development team is aware of these errors during the startup of the development server. As mentioned in the comments, these are considered of benign nature and should not trouble you.

Of course, you may open a PMR.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm accepting this as an answer. In case if I open a PMR, I'll update the response here as well.